# Grafana multi-value variables and PromQL query label filter

Tags: prometheus, grafana

I need to query network traffic consumption for my Kubernetes pods and plot Prometheus time series in Grafana dashboard.

The basic expression would be such:

`sum by(pod) (rate(container_network_receive_bytes_total{}[1m]))`

It will report pod names like "XXXX-57d84d77b7-px6g5, where XXXX is the name of deployment and the rest if autogenerated by Kubernetes.

Now, I want to give my dashboard users a filter to query by the deployment (which would have one or mode pods each), so I made a variable and pulled deployment names there via query, so I have XXXX or ZZZZ there, without the autogenerated pards, nice and dandy, the query now looks like:

`sum by(pod) (rate(container_network_receive_bytes_total{pod_name=~"$deployment.*"}[1m]))`

I get my results just fine, the magic in action.

Now, I enable "multi-value" and "all values" (with ".*" expression), and my query on examination becomes

`sum by(pod) (rate(container_network_receive_bytes_total{pod_name=~"XXX|YYY|ZZZ.*"}[1m]))`

Obviously, I will get only ZZZ results, as to get the rest, my substitute has to become `pod_name=~"XXX.*|YYY.*|ZZZ.*"`

By now, I pertty much tried everything I could imagine to make it right, but this multi-value case is not working for me.

Any alternative ideas, please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using `"$(deployment)-.*"` as the regex so the suffix is properly distributed.

Comment: Thanks for suggestion, I'm not sure what was I thinking :)
Syntax is slightly different, but the spirit is there:
container_name=~"($deployment).*"}